# Memcached::get(): could not unserialize value

Tags: php, memcached

I have a weird bug with Memcached. I get data from MySQL via Doctrine and save the result in Memcached. On of the fields is serialized table

```
a:20:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:1;i:2;i:2;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:5;i:9;i:6;i:10;i:7;i:11;i:8;i:3;i:9;i:6;i:10;i:7;i:11;i:8;i:12;i:12;i:13;i:13;i:14;i:14;i:15;i:15;i:16;i:16;i:17;i:17;i:18;i:18;i:19;i:19;}
```

It is perfectly OK, this table unserialize correctly. But recently I got weird error with Memcached:

```
Memcached::get(): could not unserialize value
```

Any guess what is going on? Others rows which also uses serialized data works fine. One of the rows even have the same array serialized and it works.

Comment: Have you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35200567/3081659 ?